# Moving a record after TTL expiry

Tags: cassandra, ttl

I have two tables, a normal table and it's archived version. The rows in the normal table need to be moved to the archived version after TTL expires on the row. How can I accomplish this?

Is there a native trigger feature in Cassandra that I can use to move the record over to the audit table?

I know how to do this using code, but I thought that a batch process or even an event driven process to move it is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no, there is no way to achieve this without writing code for it.

When TTL is expired and when the record is read after that, the record will be marked as tombstone and once the gc grace period is finished, it is removed from the disk. There is no control over these operations/events and hence there is no way, including triggers, to instruct cassandra to insert this row into some other table.